# Some crazy kick identification

Tags: kicking

So, I [stumbled on this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r3OB.jpg) and I have a few questions...

[image: This is some crazy kick]

What martial art is this? Is this allowed in competitions?  What is this kick called?  What is this sorcery?

^_~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## ROLLING THUNDER

> Kyokushin competition is also the home of the rolling thunder, or *Do mawashi geri* / *Kaiten geri*. Because of the rules it is relatively low risk, but tremendously high reward. Bouts are fought so close in, and so ferociously, that a quick push away is almost guaranteed to have the opponent lunging back in. And, if you've been trading body punches, his hands will probably be down.
>
> When it comes to the rolling thunder, Peter Graham is the absolute man. He could throw it in combination, on the counter, and pretty much any time you wouldn't expect it. He even knocked out the great Badr Hari with it. I don't know if the rolling thunder will ever catch on in a big way in MMA, because it is essentially throwing yourself into guard... but against Max Holloway, Conor McGregor at least had a go at it.

From Jack Slack's [FIGHTING MOTIVES: HOW RULES CHANGE STYLES](http://fightland.vice.com/blog/fighting-motives-how-rules-change-styles), on the Fightland blog.

Answer (score 9):

One name it goes by in Japanese martial arts is *[Do Mawashi Kaiten Geri](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZL6T3eoZNs)*, sometimes known as the "forward roll axe kick". It does appear in other styles. In Capoeira, it's often referred to as an *Aú Chibata* and differs in that actually rolling, rather than springing forward on your hands and landing on the non-kicking foot, is considered to be bad form.